# Laravel testing undefined method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I try to write tests in laravel, but I can't even run example test, bcs I get error:

```
λ phpunit
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in E:\www\ikcms\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1042
Stack trace:
#0 E:\www\ikcms\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(163): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 E:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in E:\www\ikcms\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1042

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Util_Configuration::getTestdoxGroupConfiguration() in E:\www\ikcms\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:1042
Stack trace:
#0 E:\www\ikcms\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php(163): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->handleConfiguration(Array)
#1 E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(176): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#2 E:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#3 E:\xampp\php\phpunit(46): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#4 {main}
  thrown in E:\www\ikcms\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php on line 1042
```

Of course, it happens after downloading laravel.

Laravel version: 5.3
PHPUnit: 5.0

Comment: I've this same error after update composer package.

Answer (score 3):

If you use phpunit across multiple projects it's often easier to not mess with a globally installed phpunit but to run it from your project's vendor folder.

You can check your project with:

```
composer info phpunit/phpunit
```

(If you see an `[InvalidArgumentException] Package phpunit/phpunit not found` then I would `composer require phpunit/phpunit --dev`)

Since [Laravel includes phpunit by default](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/bf33e1702217bc5ea71387dafe6623b922f68b74/composer.json#L15) you more than likely can run

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit …
```

and also

```
composer exec 'phpunit …'
```

and you can be certain that you're running the version of phpunit specified in that project's composer.json.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error before upgrading Laravel's dependencies inculding phpunit.
The update gives the version 5.7.6 of PHPUnit instead of the version 5.6.*.
If you use the PHPUnit of your computer path it will gives you this error.
I think it will be fixed but for the moment you can execute PHPUnit with the binary included in your Composer's vendor by writing `php vendor/bin/phpunit` on your project root. For me it works, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

As @julien-metral said, the version of PHPUnit installed globally on you computer is older than the version used in Laravel 5.4. You can upgrade it by editing `~/.composer/composer.json` file and changing `phpunit/phpunit` dependency version to

```
"phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
```

After that you should run `composer global update`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Windows. Just create phpunit.bat near to phpunit.xml and then put this script into phpunit.bat.

CALL vendor\bin\phpunit

thats all. Then just try to run phpunit.